# LibGdx animation using TextureAtlas

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm trying to load an explosion animation. The animations consists of 16 frames, all saved in the file Explosion.png. In my game, all the images are stored in a texture atlas pack.

So first i got the region that i needed from the class Assets.java

```
public class Explosion {
    public final AtlasRegion explosion;
    public Explosion (TextureAtlas atlas){
        explosion = atlas.findRegion(Constants.EXPLOSION);
    }
}
```

Then in my class which will create the explosion, I have the following code:

```
public Particles(Vector2 position){
    this.position = position;
    startTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();

    Array<TextureRegion> explosionAnimationTexture = new Array<TextureRegion>();

    TextureRegion region = Assets.instance.explosion.explosion;
    Texture explosionTexture = region.getTexture();

    int ROW = 4;  // rows of sprite sheet image
    int COLUMN = 4;
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(explosionTexture, explosionTexture.getWidth() / COLUMN, explosionTexture.getHeight() / ROW);
    TextureRegion[] frames = new TextureRegion[ROW * COLUMN];
    int elementIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMN; j++) {
            explosionAnimationTexture.add(tmp[i][j]);
            frames[elementIndex++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }

    explosion = new Animation(EXPLOSION_FRAME_DURATION,explosionAnimationTexture , Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG);
}
```

I'm using 4x4 since I have 16 frame. And inside the render method i got the following:

```
public void render(SpriteBatch batch){
    float elapsedTime = MathUtils.nanoToSec * (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - startTime);
    TextureRegion walkLoopTexture = explosion.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime);

    batch.draw(
            walkLoopTexture.getTexture(),
            position.x,
            position.y,
            0,
            0,
            walkLoopTexture.getRegionWidth(),
            walkLoopTexture.getRegionHeight(),
            0.3f,
            0.3f,
            0,
            walkLoopTexture.getRegionX(),
            walkLoopTexture.getRegionY(),
            walkLoopTexture.getRegionWidth(),
            walkLoopTexture.getRegionHeight(),
            false,
            false);

}
```

The animation is working, however the images are loading from the whole atlas file, and not only Explosion.png as specified in step 1.

Comment: You need to use Animation and add each of the frames into it AFAIK

Comment: The region.getTexture() gets the whole texture for the atlas. You should use region.findRegion("spritesheetname") to get just the region for the name.

Comment: @dfour I'm already doing that in a subclass ( explosion = atlas.findRegion(Constants.EXPLOSION);), then fetching the result.

Comment: Try replace  walkLoopTexture.getTexture(), with just  walkLoopTexture.

Comment: @dfour I have to because the draw method requires a Texture.  walkLoopTexture is a textureregion. Sorry for the naming confusion

Comment: Use the batch method for drawing TextureRegions instead, https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-float-boolean-

Comment: @dfour if i use this the texture region called region in my code, and draw it, i get the explosion image, therefore the problem is somewhere in the for loops.

Comment: Please understand that a texture region isn't a texture. it is a set of coordinates that define which part of a texture to display and using getTexture() method gets the whole texture that the region is a part of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code inside your `Particles` class :

```
TextureRegion region = Assets.instance.explosion.explosion;
TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(explosionTexture, explosionTexture.getWidth() / COLUMN, explosionTexture.getHeight() / ROW);
```

replace with :

```
TextureRegion[][] tmp = region.split(region.getRegionWidth()/COLUMN,region.getRegionHeight()/ROW);
```

---

And

draw your `Animation` using `textureRegion` instead of his `texture` so choose appropriate method signature of `SpriteBatch` for drawing textureRegion.

Comment: Perfect thank you, i was looking to how to split a TextureRegion. Thanks also @dfour for the help